# is there any way in Mockito I set a rule to return a value when a property of a specific object type is called?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I am trying to do the follow (Im sure there is a way, but I cant figure it out).

The problem:

There is a private method in my class, the class was injected using @InjectedMocks.

The private method calls a service and sends as parameter a property from a privated object.

Something like this

```
private MyObject myObject = new Object();

public void main(){
    doSomething();
}

private void doSomething(){
   someService(mObject.getValue);
}
```

The problem is that my object is not that easy and it has an annotation that gives it the value. Seems like with @InjectedMocks the value is never assigned and myObject is always null.

Since both the method and the object are private I cannot just assign the value (And I am avoiding add public setters for them).

My approach:

I want to mock something like this:

```
when(any(MyObject).class).getValue().thenReturn("something");
```

So, I will avoid NP at my test.

Is it possible using mockito?

Is there any more elegant way to do this??

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have some errors in your code example.

The following actually works and prints "foobar": try to compare it with your actual code to see what you forgot.

```
public class MockitoTest {
    @InjectMocks private TestClass test;
    @Mock private MyObject mock;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(mock.getValue()).thenReturn("foobar");
        test.main();
    }
}

class TestClass {
    private MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

    public void main() {
        doSomething();
    }
    private void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(myObject.getValue());
    }
}

class MyObject {
    public String getValue() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the object or the method alone using PowerMock.createPartialMock and the proxy the method call.
For example your above code

```
when(any(MyObject).class).getValue().thenReturn("something");
```

should be

```
when(mockedObject).methodCall().thenReturn("something");
```

Comment: even if the method is private and cannot be called?

Comment: No my bad, private method can not be mocked :(